# Pass configuration object to pytest.main()

Tags: pytest

I'm wrapping `pytests` in a python program that does some setup and builds the argument list to invoke `pytest.main`.

```
arg_list = [ ... ]  //build arg_list

pytest.main(args=arg_list)
```

I also need to pass a configuration object from this wrapper to the tests run by `pytest`. I was thinking creating a fixture called `conf` and reference it the test functions

```
@pytest.fixture
def conf(request):
    # Obtain configuration object

def test_mytest(conf):
    #use configuration
```

However, I haven't found a way to pass an arbitrary object to fixtures (only options from the pytest arguments list).

Maybe using a hook? or a plugin injected or initialized from the wrapper?

Comment: You can add your own command line option and initialize any object in config based on what value was passed for this custom option. Check out the recipe in [Pass different values to a test function, depending on command line options](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#pass-different-values-to-a-test-function-depending-on-command-line-options).

Comment: Thanks but this suggestion doesn't address the main issue of the question: passing the object from the wrapper to the pytest.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a module that is shared between your wrapper and your tests or serialize the object first.

### Pickle the object and load it before tests

This solution keeps your wrapper and tests mostly independent. You could still execute the tests directly and pass the configuration object from the command line if you want to reproduce the test output for a certain object.
It does not work for all objects, because not all objects can be pickled. See ["What can be pickled and unpickled?"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) for more details. This solution respects the scope of the fixture, because the object is reloaded from disk when the fixture is created.

Add a command line option for the path of the pickled file in `conftest.py`

```
import pickle
import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--cfg-obj", help="path to the pickled configuration object")

@pytest.fixture
def conf(request):
    path = request.config.getoption("--cfg-obj")
    with open(path, 'rb') as fp:
        return pickle.load(fp)
```

Pickle the object in `wrapper.py` and save it in a temporary file.

```
import pickle
import tempfile
import pytest

config_obj = {"answer": 42}

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as fp:
    pickle.dump(config_obj, fp)
    fp.close()

    args_list = ["tests.py", "--cfg-obj", fp.name]
    pytest.main(args=args_list)
```

Use the `conf` fixture in `tests.py`

```
def test_something(conf):
    assert conf == {'answer': 42}
```

### Share the object between the wrapper and the tests

This solution does not seem very "clean" to me, because the tests can't be executed without the wrapper anymore (unless you add a fallback if the object is not set), but it has the advantage that the wrapper and the tests access the same object. This will work for arbitrary objects. It also introduces a possible dependency between your tests if you modify the state of the object, because the `scope` parameter of the fixture decorator has no effect here (it always loads the same object).

Create a `shared.py` module which is imported by the tests and the wrapper. It provides a setter and getter for the shared object.

```
_cfg_obj = None


def set_config_obj(obj):
    global _cfg_obj
    _cfg_obj = obj


def get_config_obj():
    global _cfg_obj
    return _cfg_obj
```

Set the shared object in `wrapper.py`

```
import pytest

from shared import set_config_obj

set_config_obj({"answer": 42})

args_list = ["tests.py"]
pytest.main(args=args_list)
```

Load the shared object in your `conf` fixture

```
import pytest

from shared import get_config_obj

@pytest.fixture
def conf():
    return get_config_obj()

def test_something(conf):
    assert conf == {"answer": 42}
```

Note that the `shared.py` module does not have to be outside your tests directory. If you turn the tests directory into a package by adding `__init__.py` files and add the shared object there, then you can import the `tests` package from your wrapper and set it with `tests.set_config_obj(...)`.